# Android - полная блокировка HorizontalScrollView.

Tags: horizontalscrollview, android, java

Написал программу, в которой в определённый момент должна выключиться прокрутка. Пока что сделано вот так:

```
mContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) { return true; }
});
```

Однако тестеры смогли обойти "защиту", подключив клавиатуры и стрелками докручивая HorizontalScrollView. Вопрос: как мне **полностью** выключить (потом потребуется включить) прокрутку (чем угодно) у HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: может ещё перехватить `onScrollChanged` и откручивать назад, если кто то все таки прокрутил? Там есть ещё методы "setVerticalScrollBarEnabled" и "setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled", но они похоже только скроллы убирают.

Comment: А если перехватывать onScrollChanged и отматывать назад, то это будет сразу или с анимацией прокручивания? Просто у меня в HSV находится несколько ListView, и не хотелось бы, чтоб из-за блокировки как-то пострадала прокрутка ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте отказаться от фокуса, унаследовавшись от HorizontalScrollView

```
public class CustomScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView 
{
    private boolean scrollEnable = true;
    public CustomScrollView(Context context) 
    {
      super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
      super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    //отказываемся от касаний
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
    {
      if(scrollEnable)
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

      return scrollEnable;
    }

    //отказываемся от фокуса
    @Override
    protected boolean onRequestFocusInDescendants(int dir, Rect rect) 
    {
      if(scrollEnable)
        return super.onRequestFocusInDescendants(dir,rect);

       return scrollEnable;
    }

    //устанавливает возможность скрола(true - скролл возможен)
    public void setScrollEnable(boolean enable)
    {
      this.scrollEnable = enable;
    }

    public boolean isScrollEnable()
    {
        return scrollEnable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Я потом смогу разблокировать прокрутку?

Comment: да, можно все, просто надо только захотеть :)

Comment: @SuperCreeper обновил код, сделал возможность всключения/отключения скролла

Answer (score 0):

на мой взгляд лучшее решение это создать свой MyHorizontalScrollView расширяющий  HorizontalScrollView и определяющий переменную isScrolling + геттер\сеттер. 
Затем переопределить поведение для touch и key, в зависимости от isScrolling, если true то передавать управление супер классу.

тогда если тестеры ещё "чего найдут" можно будет легко подправить, так же можно будет легко добавить нужный параметр в attr.xml дабы можно было настраивать в ресурсах